# What kind of a display should I be using?

Tags: lcd, display

Are old monochromatic displays, like the ones used on the original Gameboy (bad example, I know), much more power efficient than modern colour LCD/LED/OLED displays? If so, why are they so hard to find?

I was looking for a low-power display, either black and white or colour, but noticed that there aren't any.  I thought that naturally, the monochromatic displays, like the kind seen on the original Gameboy or industrial devices, would be ideal.

But I couldn't find any, save for some smaller ones used in Arduino modules. Most of what I find are TFT colour displays and I'm afraid that these will drain out my batteries very quickly (e.g. based on my experience with my phone).

I'm looking for a display >= 160x144 that will use as little power as possible. This (hobby project) device of mine will be portable and I am hoping to have it last for months on regular AAA batteries, with the display/device being on for ~1 hour per day.

Comment: Actually the major consumer is the backlight. Field GPS devices use reflected sunlight to light the screen (during the day) and work in color for ~20hrs from 2AA batteries. I'm trying to remember how their type of screen is called...

Comment: Transflective displays.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Last I looked (a few years ago) color transreflective displays like the ones [Garmin use](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-pdeP0Gu_yAM/Tn-DIm5lZVI/AAAAAAAAACI/aT-QWbXyFY4/s1600/P1040672.jpg) were not very widely available.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany: Oh well, I didn't know that. I never had to shop for them as parts.

Comment: I don't see why I was downvoted for a simple question about the power consumption of displays - could you explain please?

Comment: I've edited - literally reordered - the question to clarify that this isn't asking about specific products. Apparently the reviewers didn't bother reading the part where I said, "My question is".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking for parts that have a particular specification, try Mouser or Digikey.  Using Mouser, I searched for LCDs with the display resolution you specified, and found one with the following specifications:

- monochromatic TFT-LCD display
- Power consumption of 50uW at a 1Hz update rate
- 15uW at a constant display
- 1.26” screen has 144x 168 resolusion

[Sharp LS013B7DH01](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/365/LS013B7DH01_16_AUG_10-197624.pdf) - See table 6-4 in this datasheet.

Steps taken to find this part:

1. Go to the [LCD Displays](http://www.mouser.com/Optoelectronics/Displays/LCD-Displays/_/N-6j735/) category of Mouser,
2. Using the "Resolution" filter, select the resolutions which match your desired specifications,
3. Look through the results; I typically sort by price and try to find the part of the minimum cost which exceeds my desired specifications, then compare it with a higher end part and see what features I might be missing, and make a judgment call based on this analysis.

This implies that the power consumption will vary with update frequency; e.g. if you plan on playing back a video at 30Hz, the power consumption will increase compared to simply displaying a static image.

Do you have the power consumption of the color display you are looking at available?  I would recommend comparing the one you are familiar with to the result above, and trying out these search and filter features on your own.

Comment: Also, the above comment by Respawned Fluff about backlighting is important; and applies here as well.  The power consumption numbers in this answer are (I believe) excluding any backlight power use.

Comment: I did this on Digikey and found only colour displays. I haven't tried Mouser before, thank you for this find! The colour displays are the ones on the same search, and I am checking the power consumption now. This one is definitely ultra low though. Thanks again!

Comment: @Al-Muhandis: Depending on which continent you're on, the electronics distributors vary widely. http://www.edn.com/design/components-and-packaging/4413399/Special-Report--Top-25-global-electronics-component-distributors has a list, but some don't sell directly to consumers (including the top 3 from there, I think). If the corporate landing page doesn't at least link to a store prominently, you should try another distributor.